# pull-up resistor relay (low trigger)

Tags: arduino, relay, pullup

I'm having issues controlling a single relay module with an arduino. It works fine when its up and running but the relay initially starts triggered until the arduino can send a "high" signal to turn it off again. I should have used a high trigger relay instead of a low trigger one.

My question is whether I can use a pull-up resistor on the input of the relay (being the output pin of the arduino)

both the arduino and relay are powered by a common 5v supply.

Comment: Switch from NC to NO.

Comment: Does the relay have NC and NO terminals?

Comment: I can switch from NC to NO, however I would like to avoid reprogramming the arduino if possible as its installed and hard to get to

Comment: So is the relay itself actually active low? Or do you just have your load on the NC output of the relay which activates your load while the relay itself is not activated?

Comment: yes, the relay is active low and the terminal used is the NO

Comment: and I mistakenly said I could switch from NC to NO as I am currently using NO

Comment: If it is NO then why would the coil be active with nothing driving it? You'll have to post schematics.

Comment: @Lundin The relay module he is using is active low, so I assume that as soon as power is supplied to the module it triggers the relay closing the NO contact.

Comment: @BenWatson yep, thats whats happening. I should also mention relay controls an electronic latch on my mates shed door, so there's a moment when it powers up that you can gain access without using the key fob

Comment: What is a "relay module"? Again, post schematics.

Comment: @Lundin (https://www.banggood.com/BESTEP-1-Channel-5V-Low-Level-Trigger-Relay-Module-Optocoupler-Isolation-Terminal-For-Arduino-p-1390343.html?rmmds=buy&cur_warehouse=CN)

Comment: @Lundin(https://howtomechatronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/HL-52S-Relay-Module-Circuit-Schematics.png)

Comment: @BenDavis I'm not buying anything. Post the schematics, not some shopping basket.

Comment: @Lundin Sorry, check the second link for schematic

Comment: @Lundin I don't see an option to post an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this would work. You should size the pull up resistor roughly between 680 and 1000 ohms as the relay module description says that it requires 5mA to trigger the relay, but you dont want to load the Arduino more than necessary when it has to pull it down to activate the relay.

Comment: this isn't a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @Ben Watson (https://www.banggood.com/BESTEP-1-Channel-5V-Low-Level-Trigger-Relay-Module-Optocoupler-Isolation-Terminal-For-Arduino-p-1390343.html?rmmds=buy&cur_warehouse=CN)

Comment: @Andyaka I understand that there's really not much to my answer, but it does answer his yes or no question. I'm not sure how to best expound on my answer other than by asking some clarifying questions, which I did. I am happy to remove or edit it to meet any site specific requirements for answers.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: @BenWatson sorry, I didn't realize you edited your answer. This solution sounds promising. I am concerned as to whether the arduino can sink the current when set "output == low"

Comment: @Lundin Since I am new to the site can you give a general suggestion as to how my answer could be improved? Like I explained to Andy, it is unclear to me why it isnt satisfactory.

Comment: You have radically changed the answer since I posted that comment. Your original answer said _"From what you have described it sounds like that would work just fine. However, it would be nice to be able to look at the data sheet of the relay to ensure there are no conflicts. Can you provide that please?"_. When asking for clarification, we should do so in comments. Good answers shouldn't speculate or guess.

Comment: @Lundin I see, thanks!

Comment: @BenDavis The Arduino can sink up to 40mA so it will be able to easily pull down a 680 ohm resistor which would only draw ~7mA.

Comment: @BenWatson (https://howtomechatronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/HL-52S-Relay-Module-Circuit-Schematics.png)

Comment: @BenWatson There is an internal current limiting resistor, would adding an additional resistor still going to restrict current below a level that stills works?

Comment: @BenDavis It totally depends on the value of R1, however I would assume it limits the current to 5-10mA which means that the Arduino now has to sink up to ~17mA which is still doable, but the design is far from ideal. Changing out the relay module to am active high one might be worth it.

Comment: @BenWatson Thanks for the help, you're bang on there, either of those options work fine. I've actually never looked at the schematic of a relay module before now, so its all looking more achievable now